# Agrupar resultados de una consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo en mi base de datos una tabla de proyectos y una de usuarios, donde cada proyecto tiene asignado un responsable y una cantidad de horas definidas.

**Esta es mi tabla de projectos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta es mi tabla de usuarios**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener el total de horas que tiene cada usuario. Intente con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT users.name, projects.hours
FROM projects
INNER JOIN users
on users.name = projects.responsable;
```

Pero en lugar de eso me arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer para que me sume la cantidad de horas de cada usuario y me arroje el resultado tipo así:

- Miguel  5
- Pedro   7
- Juan    1
- Laura   10

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes duplicados los nombres de los usuarios?

Comment: Eso puede dar inconsistencias si existe mas de un Miguel, lo que deberías estar almacenando es la llave foránea del id del usuario y eso nos dará una sumatoria con mayor exactitud

Comment: Lo puse así para la pregunta, el ejemplo es para la base de datos de un proyecto, era solo para simplificar el problema. Agradezco los comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo usando `SUM()` y `GROUP BY`, algo así:

```
SELECT users.name, SUM(projects.hours) horas
FROM projects
INNER JOIN users on users.name = projects.responsable
group by users.name;
```

Te dejo el ejemplo: <kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eea499166ac7b4add47e2cb4877ce8d1)</kbd>